# How to launch an Android activity at random time?

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app,  which is supposed to ask questions at random time.
So it's like a passive application, which "become" active at random time.

And I would like to know how can i do this? And if it's possible?

Thanks a lot,
Jérémy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the alarm manager and schedule an alarm for your own intent at a random time in the future:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: If you think it's an appropriate answer, please mark it as one :)